# Using SQLite library from UWP App(written in C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I am trying to create a UWP App(written in C#) with the SQLite library that comes with the Anniversary edition SDK.

The APIs mentioned in this library are written in C. So if I do not intend to use a 3rd party library like SQLite.Net- PCL, how else can I make use of this SQLite library in my UWP(C#) project.

In the link below it mentions to add #include  in project property, but how do we do this in a UWP App?
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases]

Comment: i don't understand why you would not use `SQLite.net-PCL` it works just fine in UWP(c#) it works even in xamarin's pcl

Answer (score 0):

You could build a UWP application that performs basic data access against a local SQLite database using Entity Framework.

You could get more details from this document [UWP - New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started). Please note the prerequisites, it's important.

Here's a code sample for your reference: [UWP.SQLite](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/GetStarted/UWP/UWP.SQLite)